# Can't solve the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android

I was spend 1 week to solve this error for Android Version 4.0.x but still can't fix it's, So I have to come here to ask professional coder to help me on this error.

My game is working find on android 4.2.x up but it's error on android version 4.0.x.

Bellow is the error log that I copy from Developer Console(Crashes & ANRs).

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.withEndAction
at kids.games.antsmasherkhmer.play_1.translate6(play_1.java:1560)
at kids.games.antsmasherkhmer.play_1.onCreate(play_1.java:138)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## translate6 activity:

```
public void translate6()
{
    //Get Screen H, W
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
    int Screen_Width = size.x;
    int Screen_Height = size.y;

    ant_play_6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ant_play_6);
    ant_play_6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ant_3_walking);
    walking_6 = (AnimationDrawable) ant_play_6.getBackground();
    ant_play_6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ant_play_6.setEnabled(true);
    walking_6.start();
    ant_play_6.setX((Screen_Width/2)-(ant_WH.getWidth()/2));
    ant_play_6.setY(-(ant_WH.getHeight()));
    ant_play_6.animate().setDuration(10000);
    ant_play_6.animate().translationY(Screen_Height+ant_WH.getHeight()+bigboss_WH.getHeight());
    ant_play_6.animate().withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lifeUpdate();
        }
    });
    ant_play_6.animate().setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            translate6();
        }
    }).start();

    ant_play_6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            smashed_ant.start();
            walking_6.stop();
            ant_play_6.animate().setListener(null);
            ant_play_6.animate().cancel();
            ant_play_6.setEnabled(false);
            ant_play_6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ant3_smashed);

            //Update ant was smashed
            scoreUpdate();

            AlphaAnimation alpha_6 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f); alpha_6.setDuration(500);
            ant_play_6.startAnimation(alpha_6);

            ant_play_6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Kindly please help me on this matter. Thank before hands.

Comment: withEndAnimation was introduced with api level 16, that means android 4.1, so you can't use it in android 4.0.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace you `AnimatorListenerAdapter` to `AnimatorListener`.
You will must override more methods, but it will be works.

`AnimatorListenerAdapter` was added at level API 16.

Comment: Mentsutov, I see, I will change all my code now. Appreciated for your kindly help sir.